# Erro ao restaurar banco de dados usando pasta mysql

Tags: mysql, xampp

Bom dia,
 Perdi um hd onde estava meus bancos de dados, mais tenho o backup das pastas dos bancos.
 Eu peguei a pasta de um dos bancos e coloquei em:

> C:\xampp\mysql\data

E ele aparece normalmente no meu **phpmyadmin**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só que quando clico em qualquer tabela ele retorna o seguinte erro:

```
#1932 - Table 'global.usuarios' doesn't exist in engine
```

Me falaram que pode ser algo no `ibdata1` só que esse arquivo do antigo hd não consigo mais, teria alguma outra forma de anexar esse banco ?

Segue prints dos arquivos:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por favor seguir isso por sua conta e risco, não serei responsável por mais perdas de dados!

> **Se a tabela corrompida não é importante seu arquivo .ibd (ibdata) pode ser removido.** No seu caso reparei que dentro de sua pasta `c://xammpp/mysql/data/global` não há existência de usuarios.ibd portanto só seguir as etapas abaixo para que o mysql tente gerar um novo arquivo.

1. Primeiro, você precisa fazer um outro backup do diretório de seu Banco de dados inteiro (como dados e arquivos serão alterados, erros podem acontecer facilmente).
2. Abra o arquivo config do mysql my.ini (no Bloco de Notas), e na seção `[mysqld]` adicionar a linha:

   > innodb_force_recovery = 1

   Salve o arquivo e tente iniciar o mysql.

   > O valor 1 acima indica qual nível de verificação na inicialização do mysql. O valor vai de 1 até 6. Acima de 4 pode ser considerado potencialmente perigoso, portanto usamos o valor mínimo que é 1.

   Isso colocará o banco de dados em um modo predominantemente somente leitura (mas você ainda pode seguir as tabelas DROP).
3. Se o mysql iniciar abra o prompt de comando e conecte-se ao seu mysql e tente 
   fazer um dump da tabela

   ```
   mysqldump -u root -p global usuarios > global.usuarios.sql
   ```

   > A cópia da tabela exportada acima conterá apenas linhas (tuplas) da tabela / que o MySQL poderia ler. (É possível que nenhum dado possa ser recuperado.)

   Em seguida, acesse o shell do MySQL, seleciona a database com `use database` e dê um 
   drop sobre a tabela corrompida.

   ```
   mysql -u root -p
   use global; 
   drop usuarios;
   exit;
   ```
4. Reinicie o MySQL no modo de recuperação normal (desfaça a edição my.ini) e reimporte a tabela "recuperada". Esta tabela conterá somente tuplas não corrompidas. Provavelmente alguns dados estarão perdidos.

Se tudo correr bem faça uma verificação geral nos bancos de dados :

```
mysqlcheck -u root -p --auto-repair --check --optimize --all-databases.
```

Se os procedimentos acima não surtirem efeito, você pode optar por remover o arquivo usuarios.frm de dentro de `c://xammpp/mysql/data/global` e iniciar o mysql normalmente. Efetue uma verificação nos bancos de dados e em seguida crie a tabela de usuários manualmente.

Você pode obter informações mais detalhadas no manual do mysql [Forcing InnoDb Recovery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html).